# Refreshing other view from jquery function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, web

I write my application in PHP. I have this code:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            url: $("#loginForm").attr('action'),
            data: {
                username: $("#username").val(),
                password: $("#password").val()
            },
            dataType: 'text',
            cache: false, 
            success: function(mess) {
                console.log(mess);
                if(mess=='true') {
                    console.log('true');
                    console.log(window.location.href);
                    window.location.href = "mainLogged";
                    $("#cao").html('homepage.php',"cao cao ovde sam");


                } else {
                    $("#greska").html("Unesite ispravne podatke!");
                    $("#username").val("");
                    $("#password").val("");
                }
            }

    }
```

When variable "mess" is 'true' I call controller mainLogged. I want to change a section with id "#cao" in homepage.php which is calling by controller mainLogged. Is this possible?

Comment: not like this, because your control over the exists `JavaScript` lost after refreshing the page. What you have to do is, pass a query string with `mainLogged` and detect it. And change the ID according to QueryString.

Answer (score 0):

when you write `window.location.href = "mainLogged";` the rest code is useless.

Now if you want to change some section here `"#cao"` you can do it in multiple ways

1. you can use cookie
2. you can use query params.
3. you can use session

Example using uri segment(query value) :

change this `window.location.href = "mainLogged";` to this `window.location.href = "mainLogged/1";`

now catch it to controller like this

```
$seg = $this->uri->segment(2);
```

and in view check if $seg is 1 than do your staff

Comment: So, I must create method in mainLogged controller which is get string "#cao" as parametr, and then set some text into specified section ?

Comment: @goksiii here you are using CI so get variables isn't going to work you have to pass segment which is ultimately the query value see my edited answer

Comment: I understand your answer. In PHP file homepage.php I know where to set this value with PHP(I would call view with data from database), but I want to pull that off automatically with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

When you login you always end up in `mainLogged` controller's index function as there is no function mentioned, no need to send any query strings from the `ajax`, as you know that you ended up here after login. So, in this controller, just set a variable here for the value of the `#cao` and load it to the view.

```
function index(){
    $data           = array();
    $data['cao']    = 'value_for_cao';
    $this->load->view('view', $data);
}
```

Now, in the view you just echo out the value:

```
 <input id="cao" value="<?php echo $cao ?>" />
```

Hope it helps.